# Decode JSON with Go

Tags: json, go, slice, decode

I have a reaction struct like this

```
type Reaction struct {
    Id           uint   `json:"id" form:"id"`
    ReactionType uint   `json:"reactionType" form:"reactionType"`
    PostId       uint   `json:"postId" form:"postId"`
    ReactorId    uint   `json:"reactorId" form:"reactorId"`
    CreatedAt    string `json:"createdAt" form:"createdAt"`
    UpdatedAt    string `json:"updatedAt" form:"createdAt"`
}
```

And I have a function that consumes an API that should return a slice of `Reaction`

```
var myClient = &http.Client{Timeout: 7 * time.Second}

func getJson(url string, result interface{}) error {
  req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
  resp, err := myClient.Do(req)

  if err != nil {
     return fmt.Errorf("cannot fetch URL %q: %v", url, err)
  }
  defer resp.Body.Close()

  if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
    return fmt.Errorf("unexpected http GET status: %s", resp.Status)
  }

  err = json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(result)
  if err != nil {
     return fmt.Errorf("cannot decode JSON: %v", err)
  }
  return nil
}
```

But somehow it failed to display the array/slice of objects that I want to retrieve, I got no data at all. Where did I miss?

```
func main(){
   ..
   ..
   var reactList []Reaction
   getJson("http://localhost:80/reactions", reactList)

   for _, r := range reactList {
        fmt.Print(r.ReactionType)
    }
}
```

and this is the original responses

```
[
  {
    "id": 55,
    "reactionType": 5,
    "reactorId": 2,
    "postId": 4,
    "createdAt": "2017-11-18 14:23:29",
    "updatedAt": ""
  },
  {
    "id": 56,
    "reactionType": 5,
    "reactorId": 3,
    "postId": 4,
    "createdAt": "2017-11-18 14:23:42",
    "updatedAt": ""
  },
  {
    "id": 57,
    "reactionType": 4,
    "reactorId": 4,
    "postId": 4,
    "createdAt": "2017-11-18 14:23:56",
    "updatedAt": ""
  }
]
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&result) ?

Comment: still doesn't work.

Comment: Oh I was like 'where's that result variable? Is this OP's mistake?' and realized that it was in function paremeters. I'll take a closer look.

Comment: what does it mean it it fails ? whats the output

Comment: First of all, you should print the result of `getJson`, which is in type `error`. Then you can find much more precise description of what you are missing.

Comment: You cannot unmarshal into a `[]ReactionShow`: Unmarshal always into a pointer as encoding/json has to _modify_ its argument. Also: Show the actual JSON response. Is it an array?

Comment: As @Volker points out you should pass a pointer to your getJson function: `getJson("http://localhost:80/reactions", &reactList)` the rest seems ok.

Comment: @MohamadNasir here's an example https://play.golang.org/p/_PnNK64giE

Comment: It works @mkopriva, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments you need to pass a pointer to `getJson` so that it can actually modify the contents of slice.

```
getJson("http://localhost:80/reactions", &reactList)
```

This is a close representation of what you have https://play.golang.org/p/_PnNK64giE, just see where things aren't in place in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Check this playground: https://play.golang.org/p/VjocUtiDRN

Maybe this is what you want. So you should make your function `getJson`(btw `getJSON` is better name in Golang naming convention) takes `[]Reaction` parameter, instead of `interface{}`. Then you can unmarshal your array-like response into slice of `Reaction`s.

Answer (score 0):

The main error here is that you're passing result without pointer. Should be:

```
getJson("http://localhost:80/reactions", &reactList)
```

Comment: this is incorrect, if he passes a non pointer to `getJson` and passes a pointer to `Decode` **inside** `getJson`, he'll still end up with an empty slice after `getJson` returns.